# Generate new URL for popup form

Tags: urls, forms

currently Im using WPform and Popup Maker plugin to made the popup. When the user clicked the button, the popup form will appear but the site URL are still the same.

May I know is there a plugin/manual way to insert custom URL for the popup form. Example is like this page, https://scr99sg2.com/en/home, if you click the LOGIN button, a popup will appear and the URL is change to something else.

Answer (score 0):

In your example they just use a link which points to the anchor "#login2".
Try using a `<a href="#login">Login</a>` link instead of a button.